# Spring boot version upgrade to 3.0.8 from 2.7.10

Tags: spring-boot, java-17

I am facing following error after upgrading spring :

RouteConfig is annotated with @ConstructorBinding but it is defined as a regular bean which caused dependency injection to fail.\n\nAction:\n\nUpdate your configuration so that CustomRouteConfig is defined via @ConfigurationPropertiesScan or @EnableConfigurationProperties.

I tried @ConfigurationPropertiesScan or @EnableConfigurationProperties both but did not helped any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

`@ConstructorBinding` is no longer needed and should be removed at the type level for `@ConfigurationProperties` classes if the classes contain a single parameterized constructor. But if your class has a `@ConfigurationProperties` and you want to inject beans into the constructor rather than binding it, you’ll need to add an `@Autowired` annotation.

Please see this Spring Boot 3.0 [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes#improved-constructorbinding-detection).

Comment: I have anotted my class with @RequiredArgsConstructor and I have one final field in a class.

Comment: Then you class has a parameterized constructor. Can you post your code?